# Organise classes for resources reports

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a `Web` Model and Controller, this has all the actions: `Create, Index, Update, Edit, Show, Destroy`

This resource, also has some reports/stats which are coming from a postgresql function (there are more then 10 functions).

My problem is that I don't know whats the best way of organising the code;
do I need to create more actions and routes for those functions in the `WebController` or create a `WebStatsController` and put all of them there?

Answer (score 1):

You'd better create another class like `WebStats` with calls to your db porcs and `WebStatsController` with its own `index`. This is a cleaner way from the point of REST and MVC